# Angular 4 select entire object

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I have the following:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedMetric">
        <option *ngFor="let metric of suggestedMetrics" [value]="metric">{{metric.displayName}}</option>
</select>
```

Where `suggestedMetrics` is an array of objects (typescript class).

When I select an item from the list, the model gets updated with the string `"[object Object]"` instead of the object itself.

Does it only support strings? Can't I set it to an entire object? It would save me from finding it again in the original array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **`ngValue`** instead of **`value`**

```
  <option *ngFor="let metric of suggestedMetrics" [ngValue]="metric">{{metric.displayName}}</option>
```

Comment: aha - `ngValue` instead of `value`! Thanks!

Comment: @Sajeetharan how do you know ,ngValue? Because I can't find it in the offical angular.io docs??

Comment: `If your option values happen to be objects (and you'd like to save the selection in your form as an object), use ngValue instead:` https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-select-controls-with-form-directives